# Convergence of Fourier.

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence

How can one show that the following trigonometric sequence converges uniformly and absolute on ℝ?

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n^2-n}$

According to a Def., it converges if $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|$ is convergent from the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_ne^{inx}$ But what is  $c_n$ in this situation and how do one find it?

Comment: $c_n$ is telescopic, because $1/(n^2-n)=1/(n-1)-1/n$

Comment: The summation indices were very confused in at least three places.

Comment: $$c_n = \begin{cases} 0 & n < 2 \\ \frac{1}{n^2-n} & n\ge 2 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks for your input.